# How can I set the bootstrap-datetimepicker to Todays's date at 12AM

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to use the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) to allow the users to select date and time value using an easy tool.

I created two pickers using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) and linked them together like so

```
//From Picker
$('#ActionForm_LocalFrom').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY LT',
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#ActionForm_LocalTo').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});

//To Picker
$('#ActionForm_LocalTo').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY LT',
    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#ActionForm_LocalFrom').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

I need to change default date time on `$('#ActionForm_LocalFrom')` to be set to `9/24/2016 12:00 AM` and the default of `$('#ActionForm_LocalTo')` to `9/24/2016 11:59 PM`. Note that 9/24/2016 is today's date.

How can I set the date to today's date and the time to 12:00AM for the "From" picker and "11:59 PM" for the "To" Picker?

Here is what I tried here but it is not working

```
//From Picker
$('#ActionForm_LocalFrom').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY LT',
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#ActionForm_LocalTo').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
}).defaultDate(moment().startOf('day'));

//To Picker
$('#ActionForm_LocalTo').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY LT',
    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#ActionForm_LocalFrom').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
}).defaultDate(moment().endOf('day'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/08nb3bg6/) helps you. I have used below code to set minDate

```
$('#ActionForm_LocalFrom').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY LT',
    minDate: moment().startOf('day').hour(23).minute(59)
});
```